# Saving shp data to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, error-000732

I have a PostgreSQL database with multiple schemas. I am trying to save data using Arcpy to my database but I cannot figure out how to define the schema I want it in.

The postgres.sde database has 3 schemas; how do I differentiate where the table will be saved?

Here is the test performed:

```
input_fc = X.shp

output_location = 

(TRY1 -
'C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3\\ArcCatalog\\postgres.sde'), 

(TRY2 - 'C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3\\ArcCatalog\\postgres.sde'), 

(TRY3 - 'C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3\\ArcCatalog\\postgres.sde\\projects\\david')

output_table_name = (TRY1 -'a3_table'), (TRY2 - 'projects.david.a3table'), (TRY3 - 'a3_table)
```

RESULT:

```
TRY1- No error Just a seemingly random location of table output

TRY2- ERROR 000706: Output name projects.david.a3_table cannot contain dots (.)

TRY3- ERROR 000732: Output Location: Dataset C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcCatalog\postgres.sde\projects\david does not exist or is not supported

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(input_fc, 'C:\\Users\\david\\AppData\\Roaming\\ESRI\\Desktop10.3\\ArcCatalog\\postgres.sde', 'a3_table')
```

Comment: If you are able to use the Table To Table tool dialog to accomplish this once, then you should be able to go to the Geoprocessing | Results window to right-click on the tool's issuance and choose Copy As Python Snippet. Then paste that code into your script to either use as-is or learn from the syntax it demonstrates.

Comment: I am trying not to have to define 3 database connections to each schema so I have a database link to the parent. When I run the tool as you direct, I get the same problem: the name cannot contain '.' and when I exclude periods it just goes to the first schema.

Comment: Then this now becomes a problem of the tool rather than ArcPy.  Can you revise your question to show the parameter values that you supply and the exact error message received, please?

Comment: It is not, to the best of my knowledge, possible to use ArcGIS to create a new table as anything other than a schema that matches the login.  Having loaded the data, you can alter the schema after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> It is not, to the best of my knowledge, possible to use ArcGIS to
>   create a new table as anything other than a schema that matches the
>   login. Having loaded the data, you can alter the schema after the
>   fact.